# Changing transition of screen using Auto Route flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, autorotate

I am using [`auto route`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) in my flutter app. I need different page transitions for single page, for example if you are opening screen A from screen B it should open from `rightside`(Screen A should have  `transition Transitions.slideRight`) and if you are opening screen A from Screen C it should open from left side. This mean that I have to change that transition programmatically in runtime, but don't know how to do that because flutter `autoroute` works with `generated routes`, and I am not sure that I can write some conditions for that.
Please give me some solutions to fix this if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

in your router file, you can use CustomRoute instead of AutoRoute:

```
    CustomRoute(
        page: HomePage,
        transitionsBuilder: TransitionsBuilders.slideRight),
```

you can see more info here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/auto_route/latest/#custom-route-transitions